# How to select sum(max remain(x+y+z)) from MySQL, to catch sum(1200+1300+1400)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, select

How to select `sum(max remain(x + y + z)) from` MySQL, to catch `sum(1200+1300+1400)`?

```
id | user | remain
-----------------
1  | x   | 1000
----------------
2  | x   | 1200
----------------
3  | y   | 1100
----------------
4  | y   | 1300
----------------
5  | z   | 1200
----------------
5  | z   | 1400
----------------
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Class1.x))
        {
            cn.Open();
            string cm1 = "select sum(max remain(all users)) as 'total' from item_new_company";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cm1, cn))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                { dr.Read(); tot5 = dr["total"].ToString(); }
            }
        }
```

Comment: all users = (x+y+x) or the users in my table

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
SELECT SUM(MaxRemain) TotalOfMaxRemains
FROM
(
    SELECT MAX(remain) AS MaxRemain
    FROM item_new_company
    GROUP BY user
) AS t;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0830/1)

The result:

```
| TOTALOFMAXREMAINS |
---------------------
|              3900 |
```

---

The subquery:

```
SELECT MAX(remain) AS MaxRemain
FROM item_new_company
GROUP BY user
```

with `GROUP BY user` and `MAX(remain)`, will give you the max of `remain` for each `user`, then in the outer query the `SUM` will give you the total.

---

### Update

For SQL Server, the previous query should work fine, but there is another way to do so:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [user] 
                              ORDER BY id DESC) AS rownum 
  FROM item_new_company 
) 
SELECT SUM(remain) AS Total 
FROM CTE 
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/336e8/1)

Comment: I want that: SELECT SUM(MAX(remain)) AS 'total' FROM item_new_company GROUP BY user, How can I catch the sum?

Comment: @ahmed - This is what the query I posted do. But, you can't write it this way `SELECT SUM(MAX(remain)) AS 'total' FROM item_new_company GROUP BY user` this is invalid SQL. You have to do this inside a subquery then do the `SUM` in the outer query like what I do.

Comment: Thanks  Mahmoud Gamal. What is the query.

Comment: @ahmed This is the query: `SELECT SUM(MaxRemain) Total
FROM
(
    SELECT MAX(remain) AS MaxRemain
    FROM item_new_company
    GROUP BY user
) AS t;` which is in my answer above.

Comment: @ahmed - OK, so you are using SQL Server not MySQL? and you are looking for the maximum remain for each user or `comp` right? if so what is the problem with the query I posted in my answer? It should give you what you are looking for.